# Troubleshooting git fatal: bad line length character

Tags: git

Is there any way to troubleshoot git error messages like "fatal: bad line length character: "? There's a lot of questions about this, but all of them seem to be about a specific message.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is. Run

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -v"
```

in order to get verbose output. If you need really verbose, use "ssh -vvv" instead. This way you should be able to find the problem.